# JAVA, is there a way to display the name of an object in an ArrayList in my output

Tags: java, object, arraylist, output

I'm working on an application that compares shapes based on their area. It functions, I'm just trying to make the output nicer.

I have a Shapes superclass and two shape subclasses Rectangle and Circle. They both have toString() methods that output their area.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " has an area of : " + getArea();
    }
```

I have made two circles called circle 1 & circle 2. Similar with rectangles. Stored them in an ArrayList called shapesList
I'm using the following code to go through the array and output the toString().

```
for (Shapes s:shapesList) {
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
```

Is there a way for my output to print "rectangle 1 has an area  circle 1 has an area etc etc.
In the past I've set names in my objects so I could just use s.getName() in my loop. But I'm wondering is there another way to get the object name in my output

I hope I've explained this clearly, first time posting!

Comment: When you say "name of the object" do you mean the variable name you defined in your code? If yes then you should consider that those aren't unique identifiers and one of your objects can be referenced by more than one variable name. eG: `Object o1 = new Object(); Object o2 = o1` <- In this case both `o1` and `o2` point to the same object. So if you wanted to print the objects name how should it decide which one of those it should take?

Comment: The short version is: objects don't have names, unless you explicitly given them a field to store that name. Think of variable names as tools for the compiler to know what you are referencing, but they basically no longer exist at runtime.

Comment: @JoachimSauer  Thanks, once I read this a memory from an old lecture came back. I get it now

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS |Thanks for your help, I knew this in the back of my head from old lectures. Thanks for remind me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't really do that. Objects don't hold the variable name, meaning you can't just print the name of variable, you are printing:

```
Shapes rectangle = new Rectangle();
// the object Rectangle doesn't know the variable name - rectangle
```

On the other hand, you can create a variable called `name` and set it up, so you know, which one you are calling:

```
class Shapes {
    protected String name;
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

And then in `Rectangle` or `Circle` class, or even in the `Shapes` class, you can create a `toString` method:

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " has an area of : " + getArea();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `public/protected abstract String getShapeName()` method to Shape class and provide implementation in `Rectangle` and `Circle` classes. Then you will be able to use this method in `Shape.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

`this.getClass().getSimpleName();` in combination with `this.hashCode();` is probably what you are looking for - if you don't mind the length of the hashcode

`getSimpleName();`

> Returns the simple name of the underlying class as given in the source code. Returns an empty string if the underlying class is anonymous.

`hashCode();`

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the

Your ```toString()`` will look like this

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + this.hashCode() + " has an area of : " + getArea();
}
```